# How to call services from twig file to show incrypted parameters in URL?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I have a anchor tag:

```
a href={{ path('edit_teacher', { slug: teacher.id}) }}>Edit</a
```

which gives URL like:

> localhost:9000/edit-teacher/1

Here, I want to encrypt parameter '1' as I don't want the user to see the teacher Id. So I made a service to encrypt this Id.

**Service**  :

```
namespace App\Service;

class EncryptGenerator
{
    /**
     * This function incrypts the data provided.
     * @param: int/string.
     */
    public function incryptData($data)
    {
        $incryptedData = convert_uuencode($data);
        return $incryptedData;
    }

    /**
     * This function decrypts the strings provided.
     * @param: string. 
     */
    public function decryptedData($string)
    {
        $decryptedData = convert_uudecode($string);
        return $decryptedData;
    }
}
```

I have also added this service to twig file in twig.yaml.

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
    globals:
        my_service: "@App\\Service\\EncryptGenerator"
```

Lastly, 
I am not able to call this service by my twig file, below is what I am trying to anchor tag:

```
a href={{ path('edit_teacher',{ my_service.incryptData( slug: teacher.id }) }) }}>Edit
```

which gives me following error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".**

Comment: You've broken the brackets order: `a href={{ path('edit_teacher', { slug: my_service.incryptData(teacher.id) }) }}>Edit`

Comment: I would recomment you to write a custom twig extension for this use case https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html and not inject the service as a global variable

Comment: @PavelStepanets : Thanks buddy, it worked.

Comment: @Fabian: sure , I ll try this method also.